# org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException while listening for SQS queue?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

I create a basic workflow of consuming messages from `SQS` with `@SqsListener`. It works fine but I constantly get tons of similar messages:

> org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor
>   [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@372b568[Running, pool size =
>   3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]] did not
>   accept task:
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable@4c30c2f9
>     at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:317)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsynchronousMessageListener.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:286)
>   ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [na:1.8.0_171] Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$SignalExecutingRunnable@4c30c2f9
>   rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@372b568[Running,
>   pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks =
>   0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
>   [na:1.8.0_171]    at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:314)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]     ... 6 common frames
>   omitted

My configuration bean:

```
@EnableSqs
@Configuration
public class AmazonSqsConfiguration {

    @Value("${aws.sqs.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${aws.sqs.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${aws.sqs.region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${aws.sqs.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(url, region))
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }

}
```

My consumer is the following:

```
@SqsListener(value = "my-queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
    public void processSubscription(String xmlNotification) {/* Message processor */}
```

Is it possible to remove them by re configuring `@Bean`? What is the root cause of the issue and how to fight with it?

I tried to find solution by natural search and encountered with the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259400/threadpoolexecutor-taskrejectedexception-from-executor). It doesn't work for me, since I don't have `JMS`. I couldn't debug because I don't even know what to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found ticket for [spring-cloud-aws](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/373) related to the behavior I encountered. I also, find relevant [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373082/springboot-sqslistener-not-working-with-exception-taskrejectedexception?rq=1).

Therefore, solution that worked for me was the following:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQS) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQS);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setWaitTimeOut(20);

    return factory;
}
```